# OpenSSL over serial port

Tags: boost, ssl, serial-port

Is it possible to use OpenSSL over a serial port?

I have two embedded devices connected via a serial port. How can I secure communication using openSSL? I have heard of the boost library but I didn't find any sample code for the same.

Comment: Why? How long is your serial cable, that one end of it is insecure?

Comment: Actually we wan to authenticate the device/client. We use normal serial cable.

Comment: A simple way to do this is using PPP to tunnel an IP connection over serial.  Then you can just use ssh as you normally would over an IP connection.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're mainly after authenticating the devices, as opposed to securing the connection itself. SSL/TLS is mainly used for securing the connection, which you probably don't need over a serial cable.

What you could do is use certificates (or even plain asymmetric keys, if you can establish trust manually).

You could design a system when one device would send a random challenge to the other, expecting a signed response in return (along with the public key/certificate of the signing device). Verifying the signature and the certificate should authenticate the remote device.

You can do this with OpenSSL, but this has nothing to do with SSL/TLS. (OpenSSL is a library that does much more than SSL.)